# Proving the symmetry of an equivalence relation

Tags: logic, relations, equivalence-relations, symmetry

**When proving the symmetry of an equivalence relation, must each equivalence class be 
closed under symmetry.**

for example:

the relation

both x and y > 10

or

both x and y < 10

across all integers.

**this clearly has two equivalence classes, the first being all numbers greater than 10
and the second being all numbers less than 10.**

take
x = 12
y = 17

**so:**

12 and 17 > 10

**and then symmetrically:**

12 and 17 < 10

**It has kept within the relation but has moved to the other equivalence class. is it 
still an equivalence relation?**

Comment: "and then symmetrically: 12 and 17 < 10" Absolutely quite deadly sure about that?

Comment: What about $x=3$, $y=11$?

Answer (score 1):

You're not understanding the property of symmetry held by all equivalence relations.

The relation here is $$x R y \iff (x > 10 \;\land \;y> 10)\;\text{ or } \;(x < 10 \;\land \;y < 10).$$

So, if $xRy$, we have that $$\begin{align} x R y &\iff (x > 10 \land y > 10) \lor (x \lt 10 \land y<10) \\ \\ & \iff (y > 10 \land x > 10) \lor (y\lt 10 \land x\lt 10)\\ \\ & \iff y R x\end{align},$$ so the relation is symmetric.

Also, a relation on the set is an equivalence relation if and only if it *partitions* that set, the integers in this case, into equivalence classes, (1) the *union* of which is the entire set, such that (2) the intersection of any two equivalence classes is empty.

The classes you've identified to ***not exhaust*** all possible ordered pairs of integers: What are we to do about: $$(x, y): \quad (4, 12),\;\text{ or }\; (12, 4),\; \text{ or } \; (10, 10)\quad?$$

Comment: this needs a TU! +1